# What's the word to describe an imaginary situation that forms the basis of an argument?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for the word as stated by the title?

E.g. "Hey imagine if cats actually had 9 lives. Cats would have a bigger population than humans. "

"But they don't."

"I know but *in the context* that they actually did have 9 lives".

What word should replace *in the context*? **Basis,premise,conjecture??**

Comment: i know, but ***supposing*** they did...   I know, but under the ***supposition***...

Comment: hypothetical ? Or more sometimes "a straw man argument"

Comment: Yeah, "straw man".

Comment: Not a straw man. A **straw man argument** is one that is *based on* an imaginary (presumably impossible or unlikely) situation. The imaginary situation *itself* is a **hypothetical**.

Comment: Not a *single* word, but you can replace *in the context* with **let's pretend** to get a complete sentence.

Comment: As per Jeffory Kemp/mgb: "_I know but **hypothetically** if they actually did have 9 lives_"

Comment: "Given the premise." 
Oh, and definitely not 'straw man' That's a false counter-argument that's constructed for the express purpose of being demolished.

Comment: Thought experiment, or German *Gedankenexperiment*

Answer (score 2):

It might be  called *[assumption](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/assumption)*:

> something taken for granted; a supposition:
>   *a correct assumption.*

or *[premise](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/premise)*

> a proposition antecedently supposed or proved as a basis of argument or inference;

or *[presupposition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/presupposition)*:

> *presuppose*: to require as an antecedent in logic or fact

Answer (score 0):

In ***Grammar***, this is an IF-clause used in a condition contrary to fact: There are two basic cases:

1) - **If you had lots of money, you would be rich**. [simple past + conditional]

- If you were sane, you would not do that. [please not: were in the first or third person singular is called "subjunctive" here in English]

2) - **If you'd had [had had] more luck, you'd have been [would have been] rich** [past perfect + past conditional]

In ***Logic***, these examples are called: Hypothesis Contrary to Fact,
counterfactual fallacy, speculative fallacy, "what if" fallacy. Please see the link. [fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfactual_conditional)

These fallacies can be expressed as a present or past conditional:

- If you go, you will see him. [but you aren't going, so you won't]
- If you had gone, you would have seen him [but you didn't go so you didn't see him]
[please note, other tense configurations are possible, and I have given the most general explanation.]

At the bottom of the Wikipedia page, there is further consideration of these propositions (utterances or statements).

Contrary-to-Fact